# how create a virtual drive

Tags: delphi, virtual, iso

Are there any known delphi components or code that creates a simple virtual drive that links to a single file. example ISO file? but this time, can be read and write.

Comment: ISO files are CD images.  Do you mean VHD files?

Comment: Sort-of VHD but not the SubSt thing, like links to an existing folder. it must link to a One file. if you have any idea please post.

Comment: You should better describe what you want to do with this "simple virtual drive". Do you expect to have a complete file system in that file ? Please describe what you need to achieve because I suspect you think a simple virtual drive is a solution and maybe it isn't.  It's a kind of [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3):

Writing a "virtual drive" requires writing a kernel-level device emulation driver (a "SCSI miniport"-based drivers seem fairly popular), which generally means C/C++ -- and that is just the start ;-)

Not a trivial task. There may be some existing [open source] code solutions that get at least some of the way there...

Here are what I have been able to find with some quick google goggles:

- [Wikipedia article on ISO software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ISO_image_software)
- [WinCDEmu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinCDEmu)

  > WinCDEmu is an open-source utility for mounting ISO image files in Microsoft Windows. *It installs a Windows device driver* which allows a user to mount an image of a CD or DVD ROM and access it as if it were a physical drive.
- [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)
- [Virtual Floppy](http://vfd.sourceforge.net/)

However, if all you need is a tool *to* create an ISO/VHD from a directory and not a real "virtual drive" (or, at least a virtual driver *someone else* is providing), then that might be a far simpler integration task...

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

السلام عليكم

I use this simple method
SUBST

ShellExecute(Handle,'','subst',' Z: d:\data',nil, SW_NORMAL) ;